# build binary tree from start and end element of an array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I have an array suppose {10,1,10,9}
Now I have to a form a binary tree with start node as array[0] which is 10 here, the tree structure will be like this
first element 10[image]

here in the picture, first element is 10, now I have to select left child and right child, so 2nd element is my left child and last element is my right child.
If 1 is my left child then I am having 10 and 9 remaining to process so 10 will be left child and 9 will be the right child for 1 as parent, now for 10 as parent, only 9 is left, so this would be the left child, and so one this tree is building.

I am trying to use recursion which I am little weak and trying to learn,but my code is not working how I am thinking, obviously I am doing somthing wrong, please guide me through this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int temparr[20];
void calculateMax(int arr[],int start, int end)
{
    if(start > end)
        return;
    cout<<arr[start]<<"  ";
    calculateMax(arr,start+1,end);
    calculateMax(arr,start,end-1);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10,1,10,9};
    temparr[0] = 10;
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    calculateMax(arr,0,n-1);
    //for(int i=0;i<20;++i)
    //cout<<temparr[i]<<"  ";
    return 0;
}
```

my `cout` should output 10 1 10 9 9 10 9 1 10 10 1 but its not.